# Unresolved references when switching from Debug to Release configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been building and executing code successfully with Solution Configuration set to Debug in Visual Studio. I am now preparing a production version of the code. When I switch from Debug configuration to Release configuration, I find that my references to external classes in the code are unresolved, and the build fails. The \bin\Debug folder contains all the `.dll` files I need but the `\bin\Release` folder is empty. If I try to add `dlls` with "Add References" in Visual Studio, I get a message indicating the reference already exists. I tried copying the `dlls` from `\bin\Debug` to `\bin\Release`, but the build still fails. Can anyone recommend a solution?

Comment: Clean your solution. Restart VS. And never ever copy `Debug`-mode binaries into `Release`-mode `/bin` :)

Comment: References do not depend on the configuration, so quite hard to explain.  Watch out for #if DEBUG in the source for those external classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. They made me think. I solved the problem by moving all the dlls from the project folders into an external folder and using "Add References" to refer to them in their external locations. I also set CopyLocal = False in the properties of the references.

Comment: OK, that's the 'how you fixed your problem' answer. But do you know what the problem _was_, and _why_ this fixed it?

Comment: I am happy to admit that I don't really know what the problem was or why my actions resolved the problem. If anyone could offer a likely explanation, I would be pleased to learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

Please try these steps:

- Clean solution
- Restart VS

If this does not solve it you can try deleting all obj and bin folders inside your solution project folders. It's best to close VS before doing this. Sometimes this might solve crazy dll problems

Comment: I feel like this would've been better as a comment. It's definitely not a direct answer, as its a "maybe it'll work, maybe it won't".

Comment: Since I can't comment, the whole reputation system

Comment: Unfortunately, the powers that be has decided that if you have too low reputation, you cannot comment, and thus you shouldn't comment. You will have to post some answers that gets upvoted so that you get the requisite reputation.